# Where can I find the source for a small, well-designed C# application (for learning purposes)?

Tags: c#

Can anyone direct me to a smallish C# application that would be symbolic of the "right way" to design a program? I'm looking for a relatively simple (potentially trivial) program from which to analyze and learn.

The application should have a relatively trivial problem to solve and should solve it in a rather straight-forward way while showing off best practices/good object oriented design.

I've been studying C# rather a lot of late, and while I'm becoming confident in my understanding of parts of the .Net framework and the C# syntax, I'm having difficulties with the general concept of design and how a project fits together.

Thanks for any sources you can provide!

Comment: What is "full-featured?"

Comment: I guess full-featured was the entirely wrong term. How about "fully functional and code complete?"
The idea I was trying to convey was that the application has a relatively trivial problem to solve and it solves it in a straight-forward way while showing off best practices. Does that help?

Comment: @Rich B: What does "morb" mean?

Comment: @Agent: I recommend you edit your question.

Comment: Edited title and body. Does it make any more sense now?

Comment: This is an excellent question, and I doubt that there is a good answer.  I have been wanting such an answer, and have been considering a project to provide it.  I am also particularly interested in illustrating how to organize, build, and deploy such programs, for a wide variety of platforms.

Comment: @Rob Williams: Thanks for the compliment. For me, the hardest bits about learning for me these days are (a) finding an idea for a 'learning' project that keeps me interested (I'm gonna write a productivity tool for work), and (b) figuring out how to do it well so I'm not just reinforcing bad ideas.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143088/open-source-c-projects-that-have-very-high-code-quality-to-learn-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of projects on this site:

http://www.codeplex.com/

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that all of the projects on CodePlex represent the "right" way to design a program.

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look at the previous question on this topic. It's at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143088/open-source-c-projects-that-have-very-high-code-quality-to-learn-from.

To that list I would add:

- ASP.NET MVC Storefront (MVC
  reference)
- SubSonic
- Rawr (good Windows Forms app)

All of these are on Codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

A great project that is object oriented and uses best practices is SharpDevelop.  You can download the source here: http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/.  It's actually an IDE, so you can use it to write your code too.

I downloaded the source, loaded it up in Visual Studio, compiled it, and ran it in Debug mode... all in about 5 minutes without doing any special setup!

The only catch is that the solution itself is not very small, but is broken into a lot of small projects, so that is why I am recommending it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download something like [BlogEngine](http://www.codeplex.com/blogengine/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14988).  If you download the full source version you can set break points and walk thru the code and see how they implement things.

Otherwise there are a ton of projects on [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a great library of this stuff:

[ASP.NET Quick Start Tutorials](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickstartV20/aspnet/)

[ASP.NET Starter Kits and Community Projects](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/)